# Insert php variable in a href

Tags: php, href

I am planning to insert a PHP variable which holds the directory path for a file stored on my Windows machine. How can I include this variable in the a `href` tag inside my php script such that when the user clicks this link it should be redirected to that particular folder and file.

For ex: `$folder_path = 'C:\docs\test\file1.txt';`

Right now I have tried some different ways but with no success. I have also did some research on internet, but alas could not find a proper answer.

If any one has an idea would be thankful if it can be shared.
Thanks

Comment: By the way once your page is place on the web server the link to your local machine will not work. You will have to upload the file to the server.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="' . $folder_path . '">Link text</a>';
```

Please note that you must use the path relative to your domain and, if the folder path is outside the public htdocs directory, it will not work.

EDIT: maybe i misreaded the question; you have a file on your pc and want to insert the path on the html page, and then send it to the server?

Answer (score 32):

You could try:

```
<a href="<?php echo $directory ?>">The link to the file</a>
```

Or for PHP 5.4+ (`<?=` is the PHP [short echo tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)):

```
<a href="<?= $directory ?>">The link to the file</a>
```

But your path is relative to the server, don't forget that.

Answer (score 4):

in php

```
echo '<a href="' . $folder_path . '">Link text</a>';
```

or

```
<a href="<?=$folder_path?>">Link text</a>;
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo $folder_path ?>">Link text</a>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `printf` function or the concatination operator

http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php