# I'm trying to make an embed code for my flow player it's not working?

Tags: php, html, flowplayer

Here is the code, it's not displaying the embed part, why is it not displaying?

```
    <div id="content">
<?php
    $video = $_GET['video'];
    $data_id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
?>
<a href="videos/<?php echo $video; ?>"   
style="display:block;width:100%;height:400px;"   
id="player"></a>
<br>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <!--This is where the embed code will display the video-->
    <a href="videos/<?php echo $video; ?>">
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe providing us with some more detail and not just showing us code will help. :)

Comment: Sorry, im trying to add an embed link for my videos so users can view the videos on other pages like <embed>VIDEO</embed>

Comment: there is no `<embed>` in your code though?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the PHP code with the `<a>` tag improperly. From the user [Strae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80363/strae) in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256463/insert-php-variable-in-a-href):

> ```
> echo '<a href="' . $folder_path . '">Link text</a>';
> ```
>
> Please note that you must use the path relative to your domain and, if the folder path is outside the public htdocs directory, it will not work.